# Phantom routes load index template, no 404 and no errors

Tags: templating

I have an issue regarding two (that I’ve come across) routes just simply loading the index template when they shouldn’t.

My template structure looked like this:

```
- search
 - index.twig
- index.twig
```

When I visited `/search` the root `/index.twig` template (front page) loads up.

If I create `search.twig` next to `/index.twig` and again go to `/search` I still get the home template rendered. Removing all `search` templates and going to `/search` again, still renders the `index.twig` template.

There is nothing in `config/routes.php` and there are also no routes present in `craft_routes` within the database.

I may have had these routes set up at some point in the past (the project is a bit old), so I created a new database and installed Craft again (kept all other template files, replaced `craft/app` folder) and the problem went away. Switched database in config (kept new `craft/app` folder) and now the problem is back again.

Is there anything in the database somewhere that would cause old routes to persist or be funky when the templates and any `config/routes.php` have been deleted?

I did try and look through the tables but couldn’t really spot anything that stood out, any help would be awesome!

Comment: I just tried the same setup on my local machine and didn't have any problem loading the correct templates. Do you have any sections called 'search' that may be conflicting?

Comment: Maybe some weird APC/Opcache/Varnish caching going on?

Comment: @AaronBerkowitz its strange there don't seem to be any conflicting sections, it feels like its at a database level because its resolved as soon as I switch to a new database in `config/db.php` ...

@BradBell I'm running on MAMP Pro and caching is turned off :/

I also manually emptied out `storage/runtime\compiled_templates` and cleared the cache. No plugins are installed either

Comment: @AlecRitson If you would like, bundle up your templates and a database export and send to support@pixelandtonic.com so we take a closer look!

Comment: Hey @AaronBerkowitz I've sent a request through the control panel, I will update this question with any progress. Thanks for you time!

Comment: @AlecRitson Looks like you're all sorted in the ticket.  Want to add an official answer?

Comment: @BradBell Yes! Sorry for the delay and thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to P&T via a support ticket, this issue has been resolved.

Basically I just had a structure which, some point, I had used as my navigation and was causing a conflict. Something which I just completely overlooked.

From P&T via a support ticket:

> The issue seems to be in your Navigation structure. You have "Entries in this section have their own URLs" turned on, but you do not set a template for the section. So, when a user requests 'search', which is an entry in your Navigation structure, Craft defaults to show the index.twig template.